# How to properly pass arguments as structs to NVRTC?

Tags: struct, f#, cuda, nvrtc

```
let prog =
    """//Kernel code:
extern "C" {
    #pragma pack(1)
    typedef struct {
        int length;
        float *pointer;
    } global_array_float;
    __global__ void kernel_main(global_array_float x){
        printf("(on device) x.length=%d\n",x.length); // prints: (on device) x.length=10
        printf("(on device) x.pointer=%lld\n",x.pointer); // prints: (on device) x.pointer=0
        printf("sizeof(global_array_float)=%d", sizeof(global_array_float)); // 12 bytes just as expected
    }
;}"""

printfn "%s" prog
let cuda_kernel = compile_kernel prog "kernel_main"

let test_launcher(str: CudaStream, kernel: CudaKernel, x: CudaGlobalArray<float32>, o: CudaGlobalArray<float32>) =
    let block_size = 1 

    kernel.GridDimensions <- dim3(1)
    kernel.BlockDimensions <- dim3(block_size)
    printfn "(on host) x.length=%i"  x.length // prints: (on host) x.length=10
    printfn "(on host) x.pointer=%i" x.pointer // prints: (on host) x.pointer=21535919104
    let args: obj [] = [|x.length;x.pointer|]
    kernel.RunAsync(str.Stream, args)

let cols, rows = 10, 1
let a = d2M.create((rows,cols)) 
        |> fun x -> fillRandomUniformMatrix ctx.Str x 1.0f 0.0f; x 
let a' = d2MtoCudaArray a

//printfn "%A" (getd2M a)

let o = d2M.create((rows,cols)) // o does nothing here as this is a minimalist example.
let o' = d2MtoCudaArray o

test_launcher(ctx.Str,cuda_kernel,a',o')
cuda_context.Synchronize()

//printfn "%A" (getd2M o)
```

Here is an excerpt from the [main repo](https://github.com/mrakgr/Multi-armed-Bandit-Experiments/blob/5bec0f82c4502b519afddb41c343ce705af0501e/Layer%20Norm%20Stuff/MapTest.fs) that I am working on currently. I am very close to having a working F# quotations to Cuda C compiler, but I can't figure out how to pass the arguments into the function properly from the host side.

Despite the pack pragma, the NVRTC 7.5 Cuda compiler is doing some other optimization and I have no idea what it is.

Because I am working off F# quotations, I need to pass the arguments as a single struct for this to work. If I change the function from `kernel_main(global_array_float x)` to something like `kernel_main(int x_length, float *x_pointer)` then it works, but I that is not the form which the quotations system gives me upfront and I would like to avoid doing extra work to make F# more like C.

Any idea what I could try?

Answer (score 1):

I've made two mistaken assumptions.

First error is assuming that `let args: obj [] = [|x.length;x.pointer|]` would get neatly placed on stack next to each other. In actuality these are two different arguments and the second one gets lost somewhere when passed along like in the above.

It can be fixed by making a custom struct type and rewriting the expression like so: `let args: obj [] = [|CudaLocalArray(x.length,x.pointer)|]`.

The other mistaken assumption that I found when I rewrote it like the above is that using `[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential>]` does not mean the fields will be packed together. Instead, like for C, pack is a argument, so it needs to be used like so: `[<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential,Pack=1)>]`.